# How to have "Sign Up" button redirect to another page? Adding href to the button either through the <script> block or inline failed

Tags: javascript, html

I want the "SignUp" button to redirect to another page when clicked. I tried adding href for this code through the  block and inline but neither worked. Why?

```
<head>
    <script>
    function terms_changed(termsCheckBox){
        //If the checkbox has been checked
        if(termsCheckBox.checked){
            //Set the disabled property to FALSE and enable the button.
            document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("submit_button").style.opacity = 1;

        } else{
            //Otherwise, disable the submit button.
            document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit_button").style.opacity = 0.3;

        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" onclick="terms_changed(this)">
    <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" onclick="terms_changed(this)">
    <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" onclick="terms_changed(this)">
    <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
        <div>
         <button type="submit" id="submit_button" style="background-color:#32CD32;color:white" disabled="">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You're missing action in your form, if you add `action="/test/"` in your form opening tag, when submit button clicked, you and your form data will be pass to /test

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That button is the action submit of the form. You have to add an action to the form opening tag, ex: `action="/test/"`.

Then the form will redirect (means submit) together with your form data to `/test/`. Change `/test/` with the destination that you want.

Hope this helps!